# Database connection from java

Tags: java, sql, database, passwords

I have a table named "user_db" inside a database server(mysql) on phpmyadmin. Inside the table I have the fields username,password,phone and email. I want to extract the password for a certain email. For example, I have the email "user@yahoo.com" and I want to print the password registred for that user. I have managed to connect to the database, but I do not manage to get the password for the email...

```
public static void getTableEntry(String email) {
    try {
        WriteToMySql.connection();
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(WriteToMySql.host, WriteToMySql.username, WriteToMySql.passwordServer);

        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = (PreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM `user_db` WHERE `password`=? AND `email`=?");


//        preparedStatement.setString(1, password);

        preparedStatement.setString(2, email);
        ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
        System.out.println(preparedStatement.toString());
        while (rs.next()) {
            String pass = rs.getString("password");
            System.out.println("Pass is: " + pass);

        }
```

Comment: what is the output though?

Comment: @HimanshuAhuja, no output at the moment... If i pass the email and the password as variables, the output is the password which I passed. But I want to pass as a variable only the email...

Comment: If you are only willing to pass email then you should modify your query to this `SELECT * FROM user_db WHERE email=?` and change java code `preparedStatement.setString(2, email);` to `preparedStatement.setString(1, email);` Then your code should run fine and print the password for the rows found with your email.

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi thank you so much, it works!!